# For loop in jquery gives wrong results

Tags: jquery, for-loop

I don't know why this code doesn't work for me: the result is **name1 - box5**. I want it like this:

```
name1 - box1
name2 - box2
name3 - box3
...
```

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
document.querySelector('#name' + i).addEventListener('click', ()=>{
document.querySelector('#box' + i).checked=true
});
}   
    
});
```

Comment: Post your HTML markup... You probably do not even need to use "numbered" ids... A class certainly can do.

Comment: Thank you Ivar. The other topic was usfull. I just changed var to let.